# deleting columns from dynamic matrix c++

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic

I'm trying to write a program where is dynamic matrix[size][size], where size=5. Condition is to find minimum and maximum value elements in matrix and then delete the columns where these elements are located. I filled matrix with random numbers from 1 to 50. maxsvt and minsvt are variables that equals to columns where minimum and maximum elements are located. I initalized second matrix1[size][size-n], where n is 1 if minsvt==maxsvt, else n=2. something is wrong with my code and i couldn't find it. There is no syntax problem but as i tested, program works if min and max are on the 3-4 columns otherwise it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int size=5;
    int n;
    int k=0;
    int min, max, minsvt, maxsvt;

int** matrix=new int* [size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
matrix[i]=new int[size];
    
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%50;
        cout<<setw(5)<<matrix[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
min=matrix[0][0];
max=matrix[0][0];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j]>max)
        {
            max=matrix[i][j];
            maxsvt=j;
        }
        if (matrix[i][j]<min)
        {
            min=matrix[i][j];
            minsvt=j;
        }
    }
}
cout<<"minimum element value- "<<min<<endl;
cout<<"minimum element column number- "<<minsvt<<endl;
cout<<"maximum element value- "<<max<<endl;
cout<<"maximum element column number- "<<maxsvt<<endl;

if (minsvt==maxsvt)
n=1;
else
n=2;

int** matrix1=new int* [size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
matrix1[i]=new int[size-n];

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size-n; j++)
    {
        if (j==minsvt || j==maxsvt)
        continue;
        matrix1[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size-n; j++)
    {
        cout<<setw(5)<<matrix1[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

}

Comment: The *best* method is to create a smaller matrix and copy only the necessary data (don't copy the columns or rows that will be deleted).

Comment: Unless the assignment is about pointers and explicit memory handling, I suggest you use `std::vector` instead. That will also make the "delete column" problem much easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There are three logical flaws in your algorithm.

Let's consider the following extreme case:

```
matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%50;
```

It is very unlikely, but theoretically possible, that `rand()` will return the same value each time, and your initial matrix has the same value in every row and column. This is theoretically possible, so what does your program do, in that case?

Well, according to the rules that you've defined: you expect to remove every column that has the minimum and maximum value. There's only one value. So the minimum and the maximum value is the same. So the end result of your program should be an empty matrix. However:

```
if (minsvt==maxsvt)
   n=1;
```

When the minimum and the maximum values are the same the shown code assumes that the final matrix has only one fewer column. This is patently untrue.

Even in the less extreme case when there are different values in the matrix it is certainly possible that the same value will appear more than once. Very likely in different columns. For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 1 4 5 7
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3
```

(I'm lazy, and I just put the same value where the actual value is mostly irrelevant). The minimum value in this matrix is 1, in columns #0 and #1. The maximum value is 7, and it appears in column #4. You must remove columns #0, #1, and #4 from this matrix.

If it turns out that they appear in two different columns, then your resulting matrix will have ***at least*** two fewer columns. And if the maximum value appears in a third column your final matrix will have ***three*** fewer columns.

The first logical flaw in your program is that you cannot determine how many fewer columns your final matrix has simply by comparing the minimum and the maximum values.

You will need to determine not only what are the minimum and maximum values, but also determine ***in which columns every occurrence of the minimum and the maximum value can appear***.

It is entirely possible that, for example, the minimum and the maximum value appear on different rows ***in the same column***. In which case your final matrix will have only ***one*** fewer column, here's a contrived example:

```
 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 1 3 3
 3 3 4 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3
```

Here, the maximum and the minimum value appear in the same column. Only one columns needs to be removed.

The second logical bug is here:

```
    if (matrix[i][j]>max)
    {
        max=matrix[i][j];
        maxsvt=j;
    }
```

If `matrix[0][0]` happens to be the largest value in the matrix this `if` statement will never be true. But this is the only line of code that initializes `maxsvt`. This variable is not initialized to anything. So, when it comes to the second part of the code, that attempts to remove this column, this variable will turn out to be uninitialized garbage. The analogous bug exists for `minsvt` as well.

This is technically a bug, but is somewhat moot because the entire approach for determining which columns to remove is flawed. It could only be one column. It could be two, or three. Or even all five columns. This cannot be tracked solely by `minsvt` and `maxsvt`.

The third logical flaw is in the code that copies the original matrix to the final matrix and attempts to remove the appropriate columns:

```
    if (j==minsvt || j==maxsvt)
        continue;
    matrix1[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
```

All this does is that this avoids copying a value from the minimum or the maximum column from `matrix` to `matrix`. Well, that's fine, but that's not what you need to do. Let's say that only column #3 needs to be removed. So, what does the above lines of code do?

Well, if you run this program in the debugger, one line at a time, you will make an interesting discovery: the above copies column #0 to column #0, column #1, to column #1, #2 to #2, and column #4 to ...column #4. But, of course, the above ***should*** be copying column #4 to column #3. That's what "column #3 needs to be removed" means.

In conclusion, to fix your program you will, pretty much, need to reimplement it from scratch:

1. The algorithm for determining which columns to remove is flawed. As specified, any number of columns can be potentially removed, not just one or two.
2. The algorithm that removes one or more columns is also flawed, it just skips over the columns to be removed, rather than removing them.

You must fix all of these problems in order to get the correct results from the shown code.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, i got everything you said but one thing about rand() is obscure for me. I didn't get what you mean, i know that it gives me different numbers everytime and i'm ok with it, because i fill matrix once in program and it's not important what numbers i will get, i just want them to be from 1 to 50

Comment: I meant it as an example. Although it's true that `rand()` will give you random numbers, it is also true that this is not guaranteed, and it is possible, theoretically, that `rand()` will return the same number every time. I used this as an example of what would happen if it did, to demonstrate the logical flaws in the shown code, if it were to happen.

Comment: Yes now i get what you said

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop

```
for (int j=0; j<size-n; j++)
```

The value of `j` will simply not cover all of the columns oin the source matrix.

You need *two* column index variables: One increased each iteration of the loop and which is the source index. This needs to go up to `size`; Then a second index for the destination matrix column, which is increased only when you assign to the column.

Perhaps something like this :

```
for (int j=0, k=0; j<size; j++)
{
    if (j==minsvt || j==maxsvt)
        continue;
    matrix1[i][k++]=matrix[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct my code without making any fundamental changes in algorithm and i want to share it to you, i think it's interesting. Only bug that now my code has is that if minimum or maximum values will be twice in my matrix it won't delete all the columns but i think that might be what my lecturer wants.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
srand(time(0));
int size=5;
int n;
int k=0;
int min=99, max=1, minsvt, maxsvt;

int** matrix=new int* [size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
matrix[i]=new int[size];
    
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%99;
        cout<<setw(5)<<matrix[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j]>max)
        {
            max=matrix[i][j];
            maxsvt=j;
        }
        if (matrix[i][j]<min)
        {
            min=matrix[i][j];
            minsvt=j;
        }
    }
}
cout<<"minimum element value- "<<min<<endl;
cout<<"minimum element column number- "<<minsvt<<endl;
cout<<"maximum element value- "<<max<<endl;
cout<<"maximum element column number- "<<maxsvt<<endl;

if (minsvt==maxsvt)
n=1;
else
n=2;

int** matrix1=new int* [size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
matrix1[i]=new int[size-n];

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0, k=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if (j==minsvt || j==maxsvt)
        j++;
        matrix1[i][k]=matrix[i][j];
        k++;
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size-n; j++)
    {
        cout<<setw(5)<<matrix1[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
} 
}
```